# angularjs how to handle promises in ng-if function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In angularjs , I am using `ng-show="isChecked('ID')"` in a element.  And trying to access one $rootscope.array , which is generated in other controller. My function is,

```
$scope.isChecked = function(ID) {       
    console.log( $rootScope.IsCntrChecked);     
    var mycheck = $rootScope.IsCntrChecked.find(function(v) {
        return v.CntrCode == ID;
    }).CntrChk;
    console.log(mycheck);       
    return mycheck;   
};
```

It works fine, but in console I do get error messages "TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined" for first few calls when $rootScope.IsCntrChecked is undefined. I tried to handle with promises in function, but that was giving an error.

> [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!

Please suggest me handling this error in simple way.
Thanks

Comment: initialize `$rootScope.IsCntrChecked` in the run function with a default value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check if `$rootScope.IsCntrChecked` exists before you try to `find` something in there:

```
if(!$rootScope.IsCntrChecked)
    return false;
```